# if(options.includes(bestelling) == bestelling) not working, how can i check if the input is equal to an array item?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So i have some simple javascript code and i want to check if the input of the user is equal to any of the items in the "options" array, i tried this method but it isn't working, does anyone know why/another way to do this?

```
var options = ["fris", "bier", "wijn"];
var bestelling_opgenomen = false;


var bestelling = prompt("Welke bestelling wilt u toevoegen?");

if(options.includes(bestelling) == bestelling){
    var hoeveelheid = prompt(`hoeveel ${bestelling} wilt u bestellen?`);
}else{
    alert("kurk");
}
```

Comment: [`.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) returns `true`/`false` depending if the item is, well, included. So `if(options.includes(bestelling)) {`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if an array includes a value in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-a-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.includes` returns a boolean. So you're just using it wrong.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Try

```
var options = ["fris", "bier", "wijn"];
var bestelling_opgenomen = false;


var bestelling = prompt("Welke bestelling wilt u toevoegen?");

if(options.includes(bestelling)){
    var hoeveelheid = prompt(`hoeveel ${bestelling} wilt u bestellen?`);
}else{
    alert("kurk");
}
```

You might also want to lowercase the input just to make sure the user didn't type in a name with capitals.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(options.indexOf(bestelling) > -1)
```

Comment: Why use `indexOf` instead of `includes`, which is clearer?

Comment: The fact that you don't have an understanding of why this works, is an indicator of the quality of the answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I know `includes` is also true but we often use 'indexOf' for array search.

Comment: And the question is invoked because he doesn't know about the result of the array search